# How to protect part of a collection schema in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

I am considering building my next app in Meteor. My data model would consists, among others, of objects to be passed to the client but, the content of which needs to be filtered dynamically before pushing it.

Example:

```
var obj = {
    name: "John",
    secret: "A very shy guy"
}
```

I want to be able to access the `secret` property on the server and on the client for 'admin' users, but no other user should see on their client.

What is the best approach/ framework to implement this?

Comment: You can control what to show to each user in the publish function. http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_publish

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the meteor publish functions with your collection, you can use exclusion or inclusion:

**Server side JS** Exclusion:

```
Meteor.publish("mycollection", function () {
    return mycollection.find({}, {fields: {secretInfo: 0}});
});
```

**Server side JS** Inclusion:

```
Meteor.publish("mycollection", function () {
    return mycollection.find({}, {fields: {name: 1}});
});
```

Then subscribe on your client to this publish:

**Client side js**

```
Meteor.subscribe("mycollection");
```

More info on the publish functions at the meteor docs: http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_publish

Also have a look at the parties example (with screencast): http://meteor.com/examples/parties